# How do I add a class to a WinForms project?

Tags: c#, winforms, class

I am trying to add a class to a WinForms project and put my code inside it. However, it causes problems such as scope problems and conflicts at loading the controls

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // Chess
    // 
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(292, 266);
    this.Name = "Chess";
    this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Chess_Load_1);
    this.ResumeLayout(false);
}

private void Chess_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

When I add a class, it puts me that automatically and I cant prevent that (it does so as soon as I copy and paste my code to the newly class created, as soon as I move the static main function out of newly pasted code. Than it gives me this error:

> Error 1   The item
>   "obj\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication1.Chess.resources"
>   was specified more than once in the
>   "Resources" parameter.  Duplicate
>   items are not supported by the
>   "Resources" parameter.    ChessBoardGame

Comment: Maybe show how far you got?  Error message? ....

Comment: Can you describe specifically what you've done (showing us any code as well) and specifically what error is happening?

Comment: i created a class with a chessboard. Then i added another class with c# code that governs how the pieces move, (it is MVC model). now the partial class names of both classes is similar but if i remove the names of the two similar classes , it gives me more errors such as:Error 1 Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'Pieces[*,*]' is less accessible than method 'WindowsFormsApplication1.ChessCode.printChessBoard(Pieces[*,*])' D:\Documents and Settings\Dima\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\ChessBoardGame\ChessBoardGame\ChessCode.cs 59 28 ChessBoardGame

Answer (score 0):

You can define classes after the declaration of Form finishes. You may get an warning if you try to define it before the Form class definition. It should not cause any problem otherwise.

Comment: i put a class with the following headline namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{

    public partial class Chess : Form
    {

        public static bool MATE;
        public void ExecuteAll(int rowStart, int columnStart,int rowEnd,int columnEnd)
        {               // That used to be a console application , but i am trying to put it into a class and connect it to a form. but winform automatically converts the class file to a form file. why?

Answer (score 0):

-Be sure about what you name your class.
-If it is is folders be careful about the folder name as well.

If the names are in use it will not work fine.

For more, you will need to provide more information or even a screen picture.

EDIT: It's a problem with copy paste.
check this link [Same error](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/gametechnologiesgeneral/thread/c72dee96-453d-4953-95ac-6475ed323e60/)

Comment: Error 1 The item "obj\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication1.Chess.resources" was specified more than once in the "Resources" parameter.  Duplicate items are not supported by the "Resources" parameter. ChessBoardGame

Comment: i have a class with no main, and the methods are in blue color (the methods name) like this : public static void printChessBoard(Pieces[,] pieces)
        {